# Project planning and customer tracking system

Tags: looking-for-a-script, crm

First off, sorry if this is the wrong 'stack' site, but it seemed like a good place to start.

I'm happy to report that my services as a web developer are starting to be in quite a lot of demand, and I have a few existing and potentially new customers all lining up - but I'm finding it very hard to keep track of everything.

What I'm hoping for is some (preferably web-based) system which I can use to keep track of who my customers are, the various projects that I've got going on for them, and (if possible) the individual sub-tasks that make up each project.

What would be even better is if the relevant customer was able to log into the site, and see the process of their projects.

I do hope you know what I'm talking about, and that you'll be able to offer some suggestions of either web-base sites that offer something along these lines, or of some open source solution or something like that?

Thank you

Comment: I noticed that someone had offered a suggestion of teamworkpm and 5pm, but then deleted it. I'm glad that I saw it before it was deleted, as I'm looking at teamworkpm right now, and it looks to be exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Try [do.com](https://do.com/).  I use their older software called ManyMoon and it does a good job of tracking projects and tasks.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I've had a play with this, and it looks very impressive - very similar to Asana - but isn't quite what I wanted. Thank you anyway, however, I might find this useful for something else :)

Answer (score 1):

I like [Jira](http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/overview). Its great for developer and manager alike.

Answer (score 1):

If you're still on the hunt, I found [teamlab](http://www.teamlab.com/) to be good. [This](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/design/best-project-management-collaboration-tools/) article may help too.

Comment: I've tried to use teamlab before, and while I like it, I feel it is set-up for larger organisations than mine. As for the article, that looks interesting, thank you.

Comment: teambox is good too, the latest version is very good

Answer (score 1):

If you are searching a simple tool for your tasks, you should have a look at [kanbanflow.com](https://kanbanflow.com/). I use this tool also very often and it's free.

I would use Outlook's Journal feature for keeping track of all costumer actions. I am working on a tool which can do all things you mention in one, but it's only a very early a